# What is the actual answer to "what came first, the chicken or the egg"?

Tags: knowledge

What is the actual answer to "what came first, the chicken or the egg"? I remember seeing an answer for this and I want to see if anyone else can find that answer.

> Hint: It doesn't state what type of egg. this should be obvious now.

Comment: Why would you add a hint after the question has already been answered?

Comment: I don't know who closed it, but I took the time to figure out those reveal spoiler things  hoping that it would open up again. *sigh*

Comment: Five users voted to close your question. You can see the reason for the closure in the top-banner: "Opinion-Based".

Comment: hmhmm, I saw that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Eggs of dinosaurs existed long before chickens.

Comment: yep! the question doesn't state what type of eggs came first, and reptile eggs existed long before chicken eggs.

Comment: Like often, the most fascinating thing is the contrast between answer and question votes.

Comment: yeah, it's kinda hilarious, even for the one with the downvotes here.